# OpenAPIClientAxios Interceptor to Set a header in React

Tags: reactjs, interceptor

I am using OpenAPIClientAxios to call apis. What I need is when there is a request going out, I would like to add a header to the request.

I tried something like

```
import axios from "axios";
export function jwtInterceptor() {
axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
    if (request.headers) {
        request.headers['test'] = 'test1234';
    }
    return request;
});}
```

However, it's never been called. I suspect it has something to do with OpenAPIClientAxios but not sure how to fix it.
Any recommendation please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function like:

```
const updateHeaderInterceptor = (axiosInstance: AxiosInstance) => {
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    if (config !== undefined && config.headers !== undefined) {
        alert(1)
        config.headers["test"] = "test1234";
    }
    return config;
}, (error) => {
    alert(error)
});}

export default updateHeaderInterceptor;
```

And then call this wherever an instance of the client (OpenAPIClientAxios) is created so we can pass the client to this function.